# Visual Basic: Read only Visability of Structure members

Tags: vb.net, class, structure, member, readonly

Ok, so this kind of follows after a previous question that I've asked involving structures and classes.   So referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34205240/structures-with-conditional-members) (and I am using classes now for the base) I have one member of the class that is an array (and I know that I have to declare it without dimensions) that as part of the constructor I want it to define the dimensions of the array.  When I was initially trying to do the `ReDim` the compiler was unhappy because I was declaring the member as `ReadOnly`.  While what I'm doing with the array has it's own question of feasibility to it that's not what I'm asking about as it raised a different issue that I must answer first.

Is there a way to make members of a class/structure read only outside of the class/structure but modifiable with in the class/structure without having to use properties or internal functions/subs to gain the read access?

Basically like declaring the member private but you can at least read the member outside the class/structure.  Just not anything else.

Comment: That's exactly what a property is for. Why do you not want to use a property?

Comment: Well it's really for semantic reasons I guess.  Even though the member is private it's still visible, you just can't do anything with it.  As a result when you use the property you have to give it a different name yet from the member your using it to access. Seems like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Yes. If only VB.NET supported C#'s syntax for auto-implemented properties allowing you to specify a private setter.  Still, using a property sounds like the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. On its own, there is no way to make a class field public for reading, but private for writing.  Accessibility modifiers on a field affect both read and write.

The cleanest way to do what you want is to define a private field in your class, and define a public property getter:

```
Private _dummy As String

Public Property Dummy() As String
    Get
        Return _dummy
    End Get
End Property
```

Granted, it would be nice to be able to express this more succinctly, as is possible with C# using auto-implemented properties:

```
public string Dummy {get; private set;}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I kinda figured this was going to be the answer but I figured I'd ask before I gave up completely.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
Private _some As String
Public Property Some As String
    Get
        Return _some
    End Get
    Private Set(value As String)
        _some = value
    End Set
End Property
```